# jqgrid scrollable dialog

Tags: dialog, scroll, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that has add/edit dialogs with a form that's longer than the dialog height but the dialog won't scroll.  I've tried to add an `overflow: auto` style to the dialog but no effect:

```
$("div.ui-jqdialog-content").css("overflow", "auto");
```

Although, if I change `auto` to `scroll`, I at least see a scrollbar but still no scrolling:

```
$("div.ui-jqdialog-content").css("overflow", "scroll");
```

This at least gives me a small glimmer of hope that I'm on the right track.

There doesn't seem to be any direction from the API documentation to support scrolling:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

Does anyone know how to add a working scrollbar to the jqModal dialog window used by jqGrid?

**UPDATE**

This is a total hack job but I got a scrollbar to appear and function doing the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {$("#FrmGrid_list").html('<div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto;">' + $("#FrmGrid_list").html() + '</div>');}, 1000);
```

I attached this to the `afterShowForm` event.  However, this really doesn't solve the problem because it causes other issues with other fields.

Comment: If you will not fond the reason why jqModal don't show scrollbars in your example, just post a code example with the HTML code which shows the order of loading of JavaScript files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I'd share my solution for others to reference.

The `form` element has a default `height: auto;` style property which causes the `overflow: auto;` not to function as desired.  To make the overflow scroll, the height needs to be set to a fixed number to constrain the `form` container and therefore make the `overflow` necessary.

I attached a css update to the `afterShowForm` Form Editing event, using the following code:

```
afterShowForm: function(form) { form.css("height", "300px"); }
```

Mind you, 300px is an arbitrary number that I selected for testing.  That number will be tweaked to fit my needs.  It may even be dynamically adjusted on resizing.  Who knows.

Also, using Firebug I found that my form id is **FrmGrid_list**.  My grid id is **list** (e.g. `<table id="list"></table>` and `jQuery("#list").jqGrid({...});`).  If your grid is named something other than list, the form id (above) should reflect that.

Reference link:

- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

Comment: Only a small improvement. `afterShowForm` can be declared with one parameter `function(form)` and the `form` parameter will be initialized to `$("#FrmGrid_list")` by jqGrid. So the code could looks like `form.css ("height", "300px");`.

Comment: Nice.  That's spiffy.  I'll added it to the above.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds strange. Every edit/add dialog has already a scrollable `form` with the name "FormPost" inside. This form has following style:

```
position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: auto;
```

I just tested one jqGrid with a lot of controls and can scroll there without any problem.

The reason of the strange behavior which you have is probably that you either forget to include optional  **jqModal.js** and **jqDnR.js** (see the same http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing page at the beginning) or use the wrong path to the files, so they will be not loaded.

Comment: Hey Oleg thanks for the response.  
I added the jqModal.js and jqDnR.js libraries to my script (they weren't present beforehand) but no change whatsoever. I think the height: auto style is the culprit.  I could be wrong but it appears to resize the height to accommodate the content.  The overflow never gets invoked do to the height: auto.  Shouldn't the height be fixed to cause a constraint and make the overflow necessary?  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: BINGO!  That was it.  The <form> tag has an height: auto.  When I changed that to a fix height, the scrollbar appeared and worked perfectly.

$("#FrmGrid_list").css("height", "300px");

I'll post this above too.

Answer (score 0):

This question is VERY old, but I'll add an answer anyway.

I don't know if this was possible before, but now you can simply use the `dataheight` property of the dialog (add or edit), to precisely set the height (in pixels) of the inner form. The default is 'auto', and thus it doesn't overflow.  Setting the desired height shows the scroll-bar if necessary.

reference: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing