# Extremely large JQGrid EditForm

Tags: jqgrid

So we have a grid with a substantial amount of columns. Problem is in the popup form editor and sizing it. When stating no size the form generates over the bounds of the page, and when implicitly sizing it, the popup doesn't detect the overflow and add a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will find the answer on your question here [jqgrid scrollable dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879207/jqgrid-scrollable-dialog/)

Comment: Actually found the correct parameter. Should be "dataheight" and not "height".